# What's wrong with my log4j filter ? ( It make tomcat hang up ! )

Tags: java, filter, log4j, tomcat5.5

We recently add a filter to our log4j configuration with a custom filter. 
The goal is to stop repeating the same log again and again, but replace it by :

the log + "last line repeated x times"

We have write the following filter, who works fine. But then, we have beggin to remark strange deadlock and hang up of tomcat5.5.

When we remove this filter, the error stop to occurs. ( Yes, we are pretty sure of that ).

Beside this empirical observation, the Heap Stack of the JVM has many log4j thread blocked and waiting to a tomcat monitor to be realeased.

Here is the code of our filter. Pretty basic. What's wrong with it ?

```
public class RepeatFilter extends Filter {
String lastMessage;
Category lastLogger;
int repeatCount = 0;

@Override
public int decide(LoggingEvent event) {
    // get the rendered (String) form of the message
    String msg = event.getRenderedMessage();

    if(msg == null || msg.startWith("Last message repeated "){
        return Filter.NEUTRAL;
    }

    if(msg.equals(lastMessage)) {
        repeatCount++;
        return Filter.DENY;
    } else {
        if(repeatCount>0){
            String msgToLog = "Last message repeated " + repeatCount + " time(s).";
            repeatCount = 0;
            lastLogger.log(event.getLevel(), msgToLog);
        }
    }

    lastLogger = event.getLogger();
    lastMessage = msg;
    return Filter.NEUTRAL;
}
```

}

EDIT :
Yes, theire is a recursion when we use a logger inside the filter. In fact, the server hang after the line lastLogger.log(... ). 
but we really need to writte a custom message ( the repeated x time ). We have try not to use a logger inside the filter, but we havent find a way.

Edit 2 :
I use the version 1.2.15 of log4j.

Edit 3 :
Something we will try  :

- make all our appender nested in a AsyncAppender

Edit 4 :
Wrap each appender in a asyncAppender does not solve the issue

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but isn't there a potential for recursion? Keep in mind that the "Last message repeated ..." line can also be delivered to your filter, and in turn trigger another line, on and on...

Comment: Alright, try this: after the check "if (msg == null) { ... }", add "if (msg.startsWith("Last message repeated ")) { return Filter.NEUTRAL; }". This isn't an optimal solution, but if it solves your problem then it's definitely a recursion problem.

Comment: João, we have try that before your proposition. The same problem continue to occurs : it's works for "some time" ( one minute to several day ).

Comment: Antoine, what version of log4j are you using? I don't see the method `getLogger()` in the `LoggingEvent` class.

Comment: I use the 1.2.15. I see a public Category getLogger() method in the javadoc.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

### Possible Deadlock

Looking at the source code, I see that a lock is obtained on the `Category` when an event is logged, and then a lock is obtained on each `AppenderSkeleton` to which the event is dispatched. If two `Category` instances use the same appender (which is common), then trying to log from a an `Appender` (or a `Filter` attached to that appender) could definitely cause a deadlock.

For example, there are two `Category` objects, `C1` and `C2`, and one `Appender`, `A`. `Thread` `T1` acquires the lock on `C1` and then `A`, then it starts processing the `Filter` chain on `A`.

At the same time, `Thread` `T2` acquires the lock on `C2`. It cannot acquire the lock on `A` because it is held by `T1`, so it waits.

Now suppose that `T1` is directed (by the filter) to log a message to `C2`. It cannot acquire the lock on `C2` because it's held by `T2`. Deadlock.

If you **posted more info from the thread dump,** it should be possible to tell whether it's a true deadlock and, if so, which objects are under contention.

### Possible Solution

If this is indeed what's happening, it seems that the problem can be avoided by logging the "repeated" message only to the "current" logger—that is, the logger of the event being evaluated by the filter. One way to do this is to track repeats on a per-logger basis.

```
public class RepeatFilter
  extends Filter
{

  private final Map<Category, Repeat> repeats = 
    new HashMap<Category, Repeat>();

  @Override
  public int decide(LoggingEvent event)
  {
    String message = event.getRenderedMessage();
    if ((message == null) || message.startsWith("Last message repeated "))
      return Filter.NEUTRAL;
    Category logger = event.getLogger();
    Repeat r = repeats.get(logger);
    if (r == null)
      repeats.put(logger, r = new Repeat());
    if (message.equals(r.message)) {
      ++r.count;
      return Filter.DENY;
    }
    if (r.count > 0) {
      logger.log(r.level, "Last message repeated " + r.count + " time(s).");
      r.count = 0;
    }
    r.message = message;
    r.level = event.getLevel();
    return Filter.NEUTRAL;
  }

  private final class Repeat
  {

    Priority level;

    String message;

    int count;

  }

}
```

This might not be what you want, because events on other loggers will not "flush" the category's "repeated" message. On the other hand, it's likely to compress the log even more effectively, since the same message is likely to be repeated on the same logger.

Comment: log4j must lock a file before writting it at some point, no ?. Indeed, lastLogger and lastMessage are corrupted in a multithreaded environnement. We have try to synchronise the part where they are modified : without succes.

Comment: It's not necessarily true that log4j will acquire a lock before writing to a file. Many operating systems allow the same file to be opened for writing by multiple threads (and indeed, I've seen this happen with log4j). However, I believe that log4j is probably using a lock on a per-appender basis; I'd have to check the source to make sure.

Comment: Thanks for the precision erickson. I think our problem is that the same appender is used by several thread of our application.